# Slow delay/latency running project on device in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, performance, lag, latency

I have a swift project on Xcode 9.2, running on iPhone 5s as a test device.
The project, using `GameplayKit` and `SpriteKit`, is small but still when I run the project on the device it have a really slow delay (about 5 - 10 seconds), and in general the animation even that there is no too much, is very slow. Objective-C works extra fast with heavier project on the same device. Any Idea how to improve the performance?

Comment: Some code will be helpful.

Comment: What part of the code?
It's in general slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find solution :)
In the Project Target's build settings, uneder LLVM 9.0 Code Generation -> optimization Level: I've changed the debug setting from 'none' to 'fastest,smallest' and the project works as expected, without any latency!

Here is a screenshot of the settings screen:

[image]